# Is it illegal to offer my services to a friend for below minimum wage?

Tags: salary

I'd like to tutor my friend for $5 an hour. To me, this is a reasonable price because I'm getting more out of it than just the money (practicing my skills, spending time with a friend, doing a favor for my friend).

Is this ok?

Comment: Assuming you and your friend are in an area where the minimum wage is greater than $5/hour, yes, that would almost certainly be technically illegal.  Is that a practical issue for you?  Unless you brought a suit against your friend for underpayment of wages, or you did something funky from a tax perspective, it seems very unlikely that anyone would ever care.  Plenty of kids babysit, do chores, work in the family business, etc. for less than the minimum wage.  As it stands, though, this is a legal question so it should be closed as off topic.

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could offer to help your friend for a glass of water if that's all you wanted.

Assuming US laws here - You aren't an **employee of the friend** so minimum wage laws don't apply.  The business relationship is essentially a contractual one and anything of value can be offered for consideration in order for the contract to be .  For example $1.00 or even an offer to trade an old t-shirt for services.

Now, if the value you receive is greater than $600 then you need to report it on your taxes and you're friend *may* have to issue a 1099.  But that's something you need to discuss with a tax advisor.

Comment: That's a legal opinion that I suspect is incorrect.  If the original poster runs a legitimate tutoring company with multiple clients, he could certainly contract with his friend at an effective $5/hr rate.  Barring that, however, it may be difficult to argue that the poster is a contractor rather than an employee.  You can't just declare that you have a contractual relationship with someone and avoid wage and hour laws.  The default is to assume that anyone paying anyone for services is an employer of an employee.

Comment: @JustinCave: The IRS has a test for determining when a person is an employee vs a contractor.  http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc762.html  This situation is pretty clear that the OP is operating as an independent contractor

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are fine.

Minimum wage laws were designed to protect employees of businesses. You are offering tutoring as an individual, not as a company, so the laws do not apply to you.

Comment: Downvoted because the reason the laws don't apply aren't correct.  The OP could be a company offering tutoring services and STILL only charge $1.00/hr if that's what they wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an issue if you're going to be filing your earnings on your tax return this year.

Minimum wage laws are different depending on where you live (both in different countries, and in different states/regions of that country) so you will need to look up the specific laws for your own area - it's possible that tutoring positions are not even taxable, which would mean you don't have to declare those earnings.

But for a private agreement between you and your friend, you can more than likely keep all of your earnings under the table.  Technically you are supposed to declare these earnings, and your friend likewise is supposed to declare his purchase of your services, but rarely will you actually find people filing for such small amounts.

If you are strictly concerned about minimum wage as a whole, you don't have to worry about that either - minimum wage applies to what you pay an *employee*, and as a tutor not affiliated with any company, you are your own employer, and you are not legally required to pay yourself a minimum wage.

Comment: "Avoid one potentially illegal action by engaging in another definitely illegal  action [tax evasion]."

Comment: @stannius You're unlikely to be prosecuted for giving your friend a couple tutoring session in exchange for say, 25 dollars. You are **very likely** to be prosecuted for running and establishing a tutoring service and not declaring any of your income.  It really depends on how much you make.